# Emitter resistor - why?

Tags: transistors, resistors, audio

I was told to add an emitter resistor to the transistor T1. I'ver been researching the subject and could only find vague info about the E resistor and now I'm utterly confused. The transistor here converts linear voltage change (from the DC mixer) to non-linear. How does the emitter resistor change it? Would it change the range, the linearity or what? I've been even trying to simulate it Circuitlab with no success.

[image]

Comment: What is the goal of the circuit? What is the in- and output signal supposed to be?

Comment: Can you confirm, just for my benefit, that you are actually looking for a VCO that changes one octave per volt (or changes one octave for a set amount of volts) i.e. is this for a musical synthesizer?

Answer (score 1):

This transistor is used as a converter from voltage to current, changing the frequency of the oscillator with the input voltage. Notice how the capacitor C1 is very quick charged through the diode D2 and discharged only by the collector current of T1.

So, the frequency of the oscillator is proportional to the collector current of T1. But in so designed schematic, the collector current is not proportional to the input voltage. BJT, without negative feedback is highly non-linear device.

Adding emitter resistor will improve the linearity of the conversion. In this case, the base resistor should be omitted.

But the best approach is to use IC2A together with the T1 as a highly linear voltage to current converter with negative feedback:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT8vhD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This converter is only as an idea. It can be implemented as inverted as well.

Comment: The OP is trying to make the VCO operate as a log VCO i.e. operating as 1 volt per octave. He doesn't want it to be linear because it is for a musical synthesizer (I guess)

Comment: @Andyaka - I don't know actually. If he needs logarithmic dependency, the demonstrated schematic is not a solution as well. With such a schematic he will get approximately linear dependency anyway (because of the base resistor), but  with pretty big temperature drift. If he needs logarithmic dependency, he have to use temperature stabilized logarithmic converter combined with U/I converter.

Comment: Yeah, the OP needs to explain a bit more - he told me it was intended to be a log VCO in a previous post when I asked him about the circuit he was designing. He told me "log" and I pricked my ears up because it isn't that easy. I suggested his solution was more or less linear at the time. There are log circuits around but not ones that are simple or really stable.

Comment: @Andyaka - well, in this situation I would try some digital solution actually.

Comment: @Andyaka - BTW, if he wants 1V per octave, he actually needs not logarithmic, but exponential dependency.

Comment: yeah I might have got this wrong. I'd use a CPU too but resolution needed can be surprisingly high given that gliding a sound from one note to the next needs to appear seamless.

Comment: @andy the transistor works perfectly. It does the job. I made the schematics after a breadboarded circuit. I want to know what difference would it make to add the emitter resistor?

Comment: Johnfound, it's an analog circuit, digital would be an overkill.

Comment: +1 to counter the downvolte. I agree with this answer. Regardless of whether the emitter resistor is in line with the goals of the circuit, *IF* the advice to put in an emitter resistor is in fact accurate, *THEN* it's better to do it with global feedback too to program the current more conveniently and even more accurately. This answer explains why OP was advised to put in the emitter resistor, which is the question.

Comment: Scusi for the downvote, curse of my mobile.What the heck is OP by the way?

Comment: @alkopop79 - The emitter resistor will improve the linearity and the temperature stability. It is described in my answer. OP is "original poster", i.e. you.

Comment: Thanks @johnfound! Sorry for the down vote, will correct it.